# Libgdx Switch between bordered and borderless windowed mode

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

In the documentation, it says that `setUndecorated(boolean undecorated)`

> immediate behavior of this method may vary depending on the implementation. It may be necessary for the window to be recreated in order for the changes to take effect. Consult the documentation for the backend in use for more information.

I am using LWJGL3 and I was wondering what exactly I need to recreate to be able to toggle between decorated and undecorated windows. Thanks!